# Python: How to filter row with latest date for each category and fill in the value from row with oldest date to row with latest date

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, date, filter

This is an example dataset:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['11-9-2019', '11-9-2020', '11-8-2019', '15-5-2020'],

                   'name': ['Allen', 'Allen', 'David', 'David'],

                   'Grade': [50, np.nan, 60, np.nan],

                   'code': [3352326, np.nan, 22233467, np.nan]})

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

df
```

What I want to do is to filter the latest date by column 'name' (ex: Allen). However, all info is in the row with the oldest date (ex: Grade, code), the row with the latest date all have missing data. I want the result to only show the rows with the latest date but also want to move the info from the rows with the oldest date to the rows with the latest date. Like the result below.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['11-9-2020', '15-5-2020'],

                   'name': ['Allen', 'David'],

                   'Grade': [50, 60],

                   'code': [3352326, 22233467]})

df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'])

df1
```

I'm not sure if it's possible, and I couldn't find related results.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
df[['Grade','code']]=df[['Grade','code']].fillna(method='ffill')
df_out=df.groupby('name').agg('last').reset_index()
```

output:

```
df_out
Out[32]: 
    name       Date  Grade        code
0  Allen 2020-11-09   50.0   3352326.0
1  David 2020-05-15   60.0  22233467.0
```

Comment: Great thanks! this works well, just noticed 'ffill' method can be applied in this scenario!

Comment: @AllenFan Please accept and upvote if you found the answer useful, have a great day :)

Answer (score 1):

If the actual values are always the first row of the group, you could try:

```
>>> df.groupby('name').first().reset_index()
    name       Date  Grade        code
0  Allen 2019-11-09   50.0   3352326.0
1  David 2019-11-08   60.0  22233467.0
>>>
```

If they are not always the first one, you could try:

```
>>> df.groupby('name').apply(lambda x: x.apply(lambda y: y.dropna().tolist()).iloc[0]).rename_axis('').reset_index().drop('', axis=1)
        Date  Grade        code   name
0 2019-11-09   50.0   3352326.0  Allen
1 2019-11-08   60.0  22233467.0  David
>>>
```

Comment: Great thanks! group by can be used in this situation, thank you for inspiring